# How ajax works?

Tags: php, ajax

I have 2 pages. One is form.php and ajaxprocessing.php

When user clicks on submit button on form.php, it will call the ajaxprocessing.php using ajax. This ajaxprocessing.php has a loop of say 50,000 times to do database insert query or some function.

My question is, even when, if the user clicks the submit button in form.php and closes the browser or shut down the PC, will the ajaxprocessing.php will still continue to execute in server?

How does it works behind the scene?

Comment: As long as the request has sent, it should be executed.

Comment: Once the request is sent it's at the server, closing the browser or navigating away won't affect that request, it's there already.

Comment: The server is not the same machine as the user's computer. Other than the requests the computer sends to it, the server knows nothing about what the computer is doing, so it will carry on with its inserts, unaware of if the computer still exists.

Comment: Assume, user A closes his browser. But some other user B from other end now clicks on submit button. Now will it interrupt the previously requested execution and starts a new execution?

Comment: I would recommend you to create some kind of progress bar, so the User will know that something is happening.

Comment: @user1298021 did you read my answer? The comments by Qantas, tymeJV and johnhopkis are a bit misleading because they suggest that the inserts will continue after a disconnect which is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PHP execution will terminate if the client disconnects. So if your ajax call times out or disconnects, then the PHP will stop running. This behavior can be changed by turning on the configuration setting [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort).

From the comments in php.ini:

> ; If enabled, the request will be allowed to complete even if the user aborts
>   ; the request. Consider enabling it if executing long requests, which may end up
>   ; being interrupted by the user or a browser timing out. PHP's default behavior
>   ; is to disable this feature.
>   ; http://php.net/ignore-user-abort

Comment: I didn't know that... it will also kill the processes if the waiting  time from the browser expire, right?

Comment: Yes if the browser/XMLHttpRequest times out then PHP will terminate immediately. Unless of course this setting is on.

Answer (score 0):

A way to test if the script keeps running would be to insert something like this in the bottom of your PHP script.

```
mail('your@email.com', 'Script done', 'The script is now done');
```

This will send you an e-mail when the script is done - if sendmail is installed on the server of cause. This way you will know if the script keeps running after you close the browser.

Comment: This isn't true, unless you turn on `ignore_user_abort`.